# Can I keep my own Facebook profile content hidden to members of a private Facebook Group of which I am the administrator?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-groups

I have put together a private Facebook Group for my camera club, and as the administrator, I have had to get its members to either open an account with Facebook in order for them to join the Group, and/or I have had to get existing Facebook members to 'request friend' with me on my personal Facebook account in order for me to add them to the private Group.

The problem I have is that I don't want them to have access to my Facebook profile - only the private Facebook Group. I don't want to share my own timeline with the Group. How do I remedy this?

Comment: As far as I am aware, and I could be wrong, Facebook's combination of privacy settings just don't allow for the kind of group you are trying to run. Perhaps it might be worth looking for an alternative to Facebook for your club's online gathering spot? (This makes especial sense given that it sounds like a decent number of your members do not have Facebook accounts.)

Comment: I think what I should of said is that I have set up a Facebook 'Secret Group'.  I simply want to keep my own timeline separate from the secret group, but if I 'block' those members from the secret group, Facebook also blocks them from anything I post in the Secret Group as well - I don't want that! I want them to be separate entities without them being connected.

Answer (score -2):

I have a few facebook groups. Have you tried the "Closed" privacy setting? Anyone can see the group and who is in it, but not the posts.
Secret, you have to add them from your friends list, or a member can add them and you have to approve them.